# Access project extra properties in buildscript closure

Tags: gradle

I am new to gradle and have some question about project properties.

I need to declare spring boot dependences at multiple locations in my build.gradle and I'd like to use a variable to define the version. What is the best way in gradle? (in Maven, I use properties)

My attempt is use extra properties, but it cannot access the property in the buildscript closure. I googled around and read many articles accessing properties in custom tasks. What did I miss?

```
ext {
    springBootVersion = '1.1.9.RELEASE'
}

buildscript {

    print project.springBootVersion //fails here

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${project.springBootVersion}")
    }
}

install {
    repositories.mavenInstaller {
        pom.project {
            parent {
                groupId 'org.springframework.boot'
                artifactId 'spring-boot-starter-parent'
                version "${project.springBootVersion}" //this one works
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Moving the `ext` block inside the `buildscript` block solves the problem for me. Not sure if this is officially supported though, as it's effectively configuring `project.ext` from the (very special) `buildscript` block.

Comment: Thanks, Peter. This works for me, don't find any side effect yet.

Answer (score 8):

Because the **`buildscript` block is evaluated first**, before `springBootVersion` has been defined. Therefore, the variable definition must go in the `buildscript` block before any other definitions:
[Source Here](https://wtanaka.com/node/8111)

```
buildscript {

    ext {
        springBootVersion = '1.1.9.RELEASE'
    }

    print project.springBootVersion //Will succeed

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${project.springBootVersion}")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This will not work.

First of all `buildscript` block is evaluated at the very beginning, before any other part of groovy script. Hence, properties defined in `ext` block just does not exist at that time.

Secondly, I'm unsure about if exchanging properties between `buildscript` and other part of script is possible.

Comment: Thank your for the information about the evaluation timing of the buildscript block. Is there other alternative solution to achieve my goal?

Comment: Currently no idea how it can be handled. Almost for sure via external file but it does not make sense in my opinion.