# LibGdx version variable in gradle classpath dependencies

Tags: gradle, libgdx

I'm finally getting back to the project that inspired [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30856278/libgdxs-texturepacker-with-gradle). According to the answer, I need to add

```
buildscript{
    dependencies {
       ...
       classpath 'com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-tools:1.5.4'
    }
}
```

to my project's base build.gradle file. Of course, libgdx is at a different version now. I would like to use the `gdxVersion` variable similar to the various project's dependencies:

```
compile "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-freetype:$gdxVersion"
```

When I try

```
classpath "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-tools:$gdxVersion"
```

I get

> Could not get unknown property 'gdxVersion' for object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.

Clearly Gradle is unable to resolve the `gdxVersion` variable that is in `allprojects.ext`. What is the syntax to access this variable?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27372828/access-project-extra-properties-in-buildscript-closure

Comment: @tim_yates Thanks. Looks good for a close vote.