# Using gradle project variable in buildscript scope

Tags: gradle

There is a similar question here [Access project extra properties in buildscript closure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27372828/access-project-extra-properties-in-buildscript-closure)

but i found a "workaround" which does not look like the optimum

I have a multi gradle project - im declaring the repository in the main gradle file
using

```
subprojects {
 repostiories {
    maven {..}
  }
}
```

now i also have to set these for the build script because im using a plugin !

so again buildscript { repositories ...

Now instead of pasting the URLs twice i wanted to use a property - as i figured project.ext properties are not set during the buildscript stage thus i put them
in my gradle.settings file

i couldnt set rootProject.ext.xx settings so i had to use

```
gradle.ext {
 mavenURLs =  [ companyURL1, companyURL2 ... etc]
}
```

Now i could use gradle.ext.mavenURLs in my build.gradle file

Is there a better way ? 
Is there a way to set the buildscript and dependency repositories for all project in one block without repeating once for buildscript and once for the dependency ?

Answer (score 2):

```
def repoClosure = { RepositoryHandler repoHandler ->
    repoHandler.mavenLocal()
    repoHandler.mavenCentral()
    ['http://mycompany/repo1', 'http://mycompany/repo2'].each { mavenURL ->
        repoHandler.maven {
            url mavenURL
            credentials {
                username 'foo'
                password 'bar'
            }
        }
    }
}
project.with {
    allprojects {
        repoClosure(buildscript.repositories)
        repoClosure(repositories)
    }
}
```

Comment: Great thank you, where can i find something about the "project.with" keyword ? Couldn't find it in the DSL

Comment: It's a groovy feature, not a gradle feature. The `with` method is available on every object.  https://objectpartners.com/2014/07/09/groovys-with-and-multiple-assignment/

Comment: Thanks, i understand the with feature with simple container objects - but why is it used in your example ? Wouldn't just allprojects {
        repoClosure(buildscript.repositories)
        repoClosure(repositories)
    } already work ? since you are basically calling only a method with repoClosure()

Comment: You don't need `project.with` inside `build.gradle` since the project object is implicit.    If writing a plugin, `project.with {...}` is very handy as you can use the same code as `build.gradle`. You mentioned plugins, I assumed you were doing this via a plugin

Comment: I had'nt had a chance to verify the answer when i did, it did not work for me either

Answer (score 0):

Simply create `my-repositories.gradle` file, with content like:

```
def repoClosure = {
    maven {
        url uri("${rootProject.rootDir}/offline-repository")
    }
    google()
    mavenCentral()

    ['http://mycompany/repo1', 'http://mycompany/repo2'].each { mavenURL ->
        maven {
            url mavenURL
            credentials {
                username 'my-name'
                password 'my-password'
            }
        }
    }
}
project.with {
    allprojects {
        buildscript {
            ext.myVariable = "Just an example!"
            repositories(repoClosure)
        }
        repositories(repoClosure)
    }
}
```

Then in your `build.gradle` `apply` it, like:

```
buildscript {
    apply from: './my-repositories.gradle'

    ext {
        kotlin_version = '1.5.30'
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.0.4'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

// ...
```